# Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:

Tags: java, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-delivery

everyone! In my TeamCity CI I get the following bug in all builds -

*Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://bitbucket.org/: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://bitbucket.org/'*

I've already faced a similar problem on this server before and was helped by replacing OpenJDK-8 with OracleJDK-13. But now the problem is repeated :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try providing credentials to the JGit command object using CredentialsProvider and then execute call()